# Add listener spring web after Applicationcontext is loaded

Tags: java, spring, listener, applicationcontext, spring-web

I'm not sure if it's working, we have a project that loads a file `.txt`, that is users created on previous deployments. The problem was that the `Applicationcontext` wasn't loaded, and throws `NullPointerException`, since the method that loads the file is @Autowired and this is what I did trying to solve it:

```
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationEvent;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationListener;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class TestListener implements ApplicationListener{

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(ApplicationEvent event) {
    }
}
```

this is the web.xml for the project and the listener:

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>TestListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

The point is to create a listener, is this correct?

Comment: How do you mean, "the Applicationcontext wasn't loaded"? What "says NullPointerException"? What Spring version is this? Have you seen this: https://spring.io/blog/2015/02/11/better-application-events-in-spring-framework-4-2?

Comment: The context of the applicatin wasn’t loaded when the autowired method is called and the context was null at the point where the method is fired, i’m using spring 4.0.5

Comment: you should post the stack trace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two options come to mind:

InitializingBean:

```
@Component
public class FileLoader implements InitializingBean {
    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
        // load file
    }
}
```

This should get called after the context has loaded.

@PostConstruct:

```
@Component
public UserService {
    private List<Customer> registeredCustomers;
    // ...

    @PostConstruct
    public void loadPreviouslyRegisteredUsers() {
        registeredCustomers = loadFile();
    }
}
```

I like this better; the @PostConstruct method will be called after the service bean has been created, which is the best opportunity to load the file.

Sorry if this doesn't really answer your question about the `ApplicationContextListener`, but it sounds like that's what you're trying to do.

Comment: The point is to create a listener, not to make sure that fires after the `ApplicationContext` is loaded. Thanks for your answer!